# Magento Contact Form: What is the 'hideit' input for?

Tags: magento2, contact-form, input

Looking at the Magento Contact Module (be it magento1 or magento2) there is a hidden field name="hideit".

```
<input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
```

Here the full snippet from magento2:

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, apart from being in the post validation, this field does not seem to be used anywhere in the code.

```
if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
    $error = true;
}
```

What is it used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reckon it's the same use as it was back in M1.

If I remember right it was **introduced around 1.4 to prevent spam**.

As you can see from the controller part you pasted, **it will throw an error if this field is not empty**.

*Robots are used to fill every input tag of the form, including hidden input tags.*

**If that field is not empty, that means a robot has filled the form.**