# Hideit input on other forms

Tags: magento2.3, security, contact-form

I stumbled across hideit input on contact us form

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/107656/70343

Makes sense to catch bots filling out the form. Just wondering whether it's worth adding to other custom forms? Or is this check a bit too primitive by today's standards.

Comment: what about google reCAPTCHA? are they not secure enough?

Comment: Nothing wrong with google recaptcha although you have to install things and get API credentials. So extra steps required.